# Noise in portable power supply to guitar effects pedals

Tags: power-supply, batteries, noise, guitar-pedal, buck-boost

I am constructing a battery powered power supply for a guitar effects pedal board.
There are 5 pedals and I am using a phone charging  battery and a boost converter to supply 9V (centre negative) to power the pedals.

The total current draw of the effects pedals is about 600 mA. Four of the pedals can be connected to the supply and cause no noise in the audio signal. The fifth pedal when connected to the same power supply causes a whining noise.

If it has an independent supply (which means another battery and boost converter) there is no noise.

Is there some way to connect the fifth pedal to the original power supply but with no noise?

[image]

Comment: What boost converter are you using?  It sounds to me like the fifth pedal is just too much of a load.

Comment: What about adding the 5th (and getting noise) then taking away (say) the 3rd and seeing what happens. I don't mean musical fifths and thirds LOL!

Comment: You must provide the battery and boost converter specs.

Comment: JRE, I have added a photo of the boost converter. However whilst the boost converter might introduce noise, the problem still exists if I use a 9v supply made from AA rechargeable batteries.

Comment: Andy aka, I have swapped them all around in many configurations. It is one particular effects pedal which caused the noise. The pedal in question is a Jamman Stereo Looper.

Comment: Are all of the pedals using negative ground? They most likely are but you should check.

Comment: Transistor The pedals are linked together by the jack to jack signal leads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Noise in audio devices is not *always* due to the power supply. Quite often one or more devices can introduce noise on the supply line due to its constantly changing demands and processing.

What you are looking for is *isolation* in terms of guitar pedal power supplies. This is covered thoroughly by guitar tech experts (such as Daniel Steinhardt of *That Pedal Show*, see [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4XRCjHxaYkc)).

If you use a power supply that isolates each pedal from the others, then noise introduced by one will not affect others. Note again that this is not (necessarily) due to a problem with your power supply but instead because one or more pedals actually introduce the noise to the common power bus.

Isolation circuits typically use a higher starting voltage (24V for example), and multiple step-down transformers or buck regulators, one for each 9V output. *(Guitar pedals are usually 9VDC center negative, but not always. Always check polarity, voltage, and current requirements.)*

Since this is an ***electrical engineering*** site, your question should pertain to technical aspects of designing or building such a power supply, rather than assembling something from USB/phone chargers. However, as both an electrical engineer *and* guitar nerd, I hope the above information is helpful in getting you closer to an engineering perspective.

**Edit:** Another possible cause of noise is that your power supply (battery or booster) cannot provide 600mA. Connecting a more demanding load than it can supply will cause one or more pedals to not operate correctly, and this can often result in buzzing, whining, clicking or ticking, etc.